# Живой поиск по JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

имеется файл json

```
let array = [{
  "name":"Xiaomi",
  "image": "1.jpg",
  "location":"1",
  "url":"1.php"},
  {
  "name":"Apple",
  "image": "2.jpg",
  "location":"2",
  "url":"2.php"},
  {
  "name":"Samsung",
  "image": "3.jpg",
  "location":"3",
  "url":"3.php"}];
```

как сделать быстрый поиск на примере https://www.webslesson.info/2017/02/live-search-json-data-using-ajax-jquery.html
что нужно изменить под мой json файл?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
 $('#search').keyup(function(){
  $('#result').html('');
  $('#state').val('');
  var searchField = $('#search').val();
  var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
   $.each(data, function(key, value){
    if (value.name.search(expression) != -1 || value.location.search(expression) != -1)
    {
     $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class"><img src="'+value.image+'" height="40" width="40" class="img-thumbnail" /> '+value.name+' | <span class="text-muted">'+value.location+'</span></li>');
    }
   });   
  });
 });
 
 $('#result').on('click', 'li', function() {
  var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
  $('#search').val($.trim(click_text[0]));
  $("#result").html('');
 });
});
```

в моём json есть let array = [ ]
в демке файл без let array =

Comment: давайте конкретный ваш код, и говорите что не работает, а не вот это вот.

Comment: у вас есть массив, в коде данные запрашиваются аяксом с сервера. Поскольку у вас данные в наличии, то вызов `$.getJSON` не нужен. а  `data` на следующей строк это имя вашего массива.

Comment: у меня тоже файл будет лежать на сервере, так что вызов должен быть

Comment: если у вас в файле написано `let array = ` то это не json файл

Comment: я думал, раз он отдельно в формате json то это он и есть

Comment: JSON это вот сам массив `[{...}, {...}, ....]` а `let array = ....` это js-код

Comment: подскажите как в соседней моей теме https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1239875 избавиться от let array

Comment: очевидно, не надо в json файле писать js-код. в файле должен быть только непосредственно массив. Избавиться от `let array =` можно клавишами del и backspace